# Convert from Core PHP to Laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

How to convert a Core PHP web application to Laravel Framework. Is there any tool available to do that? Or is there any procedure to make this possible and easier. I am in need of converting this with in a short duration. Suggest me with all the possibilities of this conversion within short duration

Comment: This is generally neither an automated nor a quick process.

Answer (score 6):

As ceejayoz has mentioned, this isn't a super quick process and you'd be very hard pressed to find a tool that could perform this for you given that the process involves making sure all your functions and code ends up in the right place.

Generally speaking, core PHP has a lot of code inside each page, or inside resources outside of this that handle all the logic.

Laravel abstracts all of this and organises your code in to meaningful and specific files.

For example, you have a `routes.php` file which directs requests to the appropriate functions - usually stored in Controllers. Whereas previously you could just go to the next page name inside your folder.

You then have Controllers that contain functions, that usually return views (which are what you see).

Depending on how large your current application is will dictate how much time this will take for you.

However, I suggest you read up on the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2) and maybe trial installing Laravel to get a feel for how it works. Once you're comfortable you can begin porting your Core PHP web application over to Laravel.
There are a few "strategies" for doing this, I personally like the "strangler" pattern where you put Laravel in front of your old application and just fallback to routing through the old code. As you port more and more of the old application over, there will be less of a need for it to keep falling back through.

For the most part, your code will be transferable - you just have to find the right place to pop it.